# How to apply drag and drop function to all frames in movie clip? Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

Each frame contain 1 text field.  I apply the code on timeline.
But it only gets applied to the last object, which means that I can only drag and drop the last object.  Why?
How can I improve this so that I can drag and drop all objects?

```
for(var j:uint=0; j<3; j++)
{

    var q:Ans = new Ans();
    q.stop();
    q.x = j * 300+50;// set position
    q.y = 500;

    var r:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * q_list.length);
    q.qface = q_list[r];// assign face to card
    q_list.splice(r,1);// remove face from list;
    q.gotoAndStop(q.qface+1);

    q.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startAnsDrag);
    q.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopAnsDrag);
    q.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragAns);

    addChild(q);// show the card
}


//----------------------------drag
// offset between sprite location and click

var clickOffset:Point = null;
// user clicked
function startAnsDrag(event:MouseEvent) :void
{
    clickOffset = new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
}

// user released
function stopAnsDrag(event:MouseEvent) :void
{
    clickOffset = null;
}

// run every frame
function dragAns(event:Event) :void
{
    if (clickOffset != null) 
    { // must be dragging
        q.x = clickOffset.x+mouseX+135;
        q.y = clickOffset.y+mouseY;
    }
}
```

Comment: So wait, are you trying to drag and drop objects you're creating through code (eg `q = new Ans()`) or objects that already exist on your timeline frames?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new layer in the timeline just for your drag-and-drop code, which you can remove from your other actionscript. Put the code on the first frame in that layer. Now click on and select the *last* frame on that layer in which you want the code to be effective (probably the last frame of the MovieClip). Press F5 to draw-out the range of frames which will be affected by the code. Voila!